Why When i Upgrate Flutter My Project Didn't Run
Hello my project was running normally until I upgraded the flutter at SDK 3.22.0 and Dart SDK 3.4.0 and the pub get.
When I start debugging I get these errors exactly:
../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/rotation_stage-0.0.9/lib/src/rotation_stage_handle.dart:37:44: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.

'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(
^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Please Help me if you know what i have to do!
i tried some fixes but nothing working.

General advice: be careful with the packages you are using. Avoid packages which are not actively maintained and look out for analysis issues.

Since flutter version 3.1 button is deprecated. After 3.1 labelLarge should be used. (source)
This is an issue with the package rotation_stage. Since it does not define an upper bound for the flutter sdk see.
I have filed an issue here. Right now, you can just downgrade flutter to a version before 3.1 or fork the package and fix the problem yourself (see this for a short instruction on how to accomplish this).

Thanks a lot for helping me with my problem I use (https://github.com/timcreatedit/rotation_stage/issues/1) to solve my problem !!
